# Branching and Pushing from local fork to upstream repo

Tags: git, github

Im asking this question because I feel its useful for the community and is sort of a more advanced workflow to an average git user.

For purposes here: my repo is `foobaz/repo` and the upstream repo is `companyRepo/repo`

1. How do you set an upstream repo/branch for tracking on your local repo?
2. How do you checkout/create a new branch `foobaz/repo/fix-issue-101`, branched *from* an upstream remote branch `companyRepo/repo/develop`? (i.e. I want to create a branch (`foobaz/repo`) named `fix-issue-101` that is based off the upstream `companyRepo/repo/develop` branch.)
3. How do you push to your local repo commits (`foobaz/repo/fix-issue-101`) with upstream set so you can create a pull-request to `companyRepo/repo/develop`? (This can cause errors like `The upstream branch of your current branch does not match the name of the current branch.` when you incorrectly set the upstream).
4. How do you update/sync your local repo/branch with the upstream branch?

Comment: This is too broad, even if you are planning to answer it yourself.

Comment: @chepner I'm not sure how. Its asking for 4 specific git commands to perform basic git operations when working with forks and upstream repos.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is a mess.  The title asks a wholly overbroad 
and/or opinion-based question, the body asks four variously trivial and/or badly-worded questions that even if clarified and answered wouldn't answer the title question.

Comment: @jthill the question has been answered. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your remote branch is called `develop`, and the upstream repo has the `remote` name `origin`, and you've already done `git fetch origin`:

1a. `git checkout develop` (creates local branch `develop`)

Or if there are more than one remote 'develop' branches to choose from in multiple remotes:

1b. `git checkout --track origin/develop`

which is shorthand for:

1c. `git checkout -b develop --track origin/develop`

Which then allows you to change the local name:

2. `git checkout -b fix-issue-101 --track origin/develop`
3. `git push origin HEAD:develop` (avoids the `does not match the name` error).
4. `git pull` or to be explicit: `git pull origin develop`

Comment: How do you ensure the name of the remote(upstream) is origin?

Comment: This is the default `git` uses when cloning - otherwise if setting up a remote you have to specify a name, e.g. `git remote add origin https://example.com/repo`